# Gulp - Error that only shows on Linux

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux, gulp

i just downloaded (ok 3-4 days ago) Linux Ubuntu and i'm trying to set up everything so i can "leave" Windows 10 :) 
So i installed gulp on my System and went into my gulpfile directory. 
When typing gulp everything goes trough until browser-sync starts.

Here are the last lines:

```
    [BS] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.43.104:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://192.168.43.104:3002
 ---------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: app/.

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

I wonder why this error occurs only on Linux? 
When doing the same on Windows everything works perfect :)

Thanks to everyone who can help me :)

Comment: @major-mann No Difference :(

Comment: `EACCES` Occurs when you don't have permission to access those files. Using `sudo` should work. What is the command you are running to start `gulp`?

Comment: @cdbitesky sudo gulp 
And no it do not work :(
Edit: My Build command is working and it's moving deleting and writing files so i think there are no problems with the Permission.
Maybe with the build-sync? Because it have to load the Browser and Linux blocks this?

Comment: Linux doesn't block loading to a browser (pretty common).
All the modules/components are installed and any system command used from the command line is accessible from the command line on their own?

Comment: @cdbitesky Sry for the late answer! Yes i installed gulp tried it - didn't worked then i installed all the modules i installed again and it still don't work.
I don't understand your last question but i think yes because i can start my build task (it moves everything from app to build folder and deletes sass files etc.)

Comment: @PixelStudio Occasionally a node-package will use a binary process from either `fork` or `child_process`. As your error message shows the latter you may not have all the dependencies of you packages met (outside of npm). You would have to go through each one.